# Is there any simple way to calculate the turns per volt and required core area for a high frequency transformer?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, inductance

I was trying to find some simple equations for designing a high-frequency transformer. The operating frequency will be 10-15 kHz. I searched many sites and didn't find any simple equation to calculate it. Most websites have simple equations for Power transformers (50/60 Hz with laminated sheet metal). However, I have seen some books related to this topic as references in research papers. But purchasing those books right now is not possible. It would be helpful if there is any simple way to calculate turns per volt and core area for a high-frequency transformer.

Comment: What operating voltage are you talking about. What type of application is it?

Comment: That's not a particularly high frequency. However, you do need to go study up on ferrite cores, which have very different behaviors over various frequencies. Also, Unitrode was in the business of providing many seminars (I attended a few of the power design ones) as well as some very nice handbooks and/or white papers on the topic. Look for Lloyd H. Dixon, Jr as the author of these. This frequency area you are considering is a good starting point. It's where I started, in fact!

Comment: Google "designing audio frequency transformers" and many tutorials will show up.

Comment: One manufacturer of such components, Würth ,  publishes a very good design manual on this topic  https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/TRILOGY_OF_MAGNETICS_EN

Comment: @Andy operating voltage varies. It may be a 220 volt SMPS, or a could be a 5 volt isolation transfomer.

Comment: @jonk, I've found the paper of the Author you mentioned, I think it is highly resourceful. Studying it now.

Comment: @SadatRafi, my guess is that the formula is exactly the same. The problem is that the field penetration depth for these high frequencies may not be very high in magnetic materials (depending on the electrical conductivity of the material and if it is laminated or not). So you may need to discount a portion of the core cross section to apply the formula. For this, it is necessary to know the properties of the core material.

Comment: OK, so if I covered application (a) and application (b) and left you an answer and then you said what about application (c), I'd probably say figure it out yourself. So, you see, it's not easy to make general answers to some questions and this is one of them. Focus on one application and learn from that @SadatRafi